# Replacement for MapView's OnLongPressListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a mapView and I trying to capture an event when I hold my finger on the map. The event similar to this one is "onTouchListener" but I want to hold the finger a couple of seconds before the event rise.

Thanks for your help.

Best,
David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use threads and the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event). As the OnLongClickListener is for a click event and I want to keep it pressed. When I touch the screen a boolean variable is true, and a thread start counting until a limit. If I move my finger then event.ACTION_MOVE fires, the boolean variable became false and the Thread stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can set OnLongClickListener